# Windows 10 toast notification issue

Tags: notifications, registry, windows-10, toast

I've tried using the registry changes to move the windows 10 toast notification thing, but when I went in, there was no "DisplayToastAtBottom"(Mind you, they already appear at the bottom)

[image: No registry entry.]

[image: But toast still appears at bottom of screen]

Very sorry if this isn't the right place to ask! :s

Comment: 2 days later, no answer. That's great.

Comment: You can create the entry yourself. Right-click, New->DWORD and fill in the details.

I find it makes no difference on Windows 10, at least for me.

Comment: @1ka tried that, it didn't move it up.

Comment: it is not working for me either with latest Windows 10 updates. please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this question on the Microsoft answers site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-change-toast-notifications-position/98d3efba-dd78-4a53-b4b4-9ba36b28c794), a Microsoft rep tries to smooth things over, but then later replies and basically says you can't:

> The Toast notification which you receive at bottom is by design in Windows 10. This cannot be changed.

In [this article](http://winaero.com/blog/move-notification-toasts-to-top-or-bottom-of-the-screen-in-windows-10/), the author walks readers through the `DisplayToastAtBottom` registry edit for Windows 10. The comments section is rather telling:

> MDJ: Sadly this no longer works on Windows RTM version. This trick was kind of urgent for me as notification bottoms sometimes get cut by the taskbar.
>
> Rasool: Please update this to build 10240 and later
>
> Sergey Tkachenko (author): It does not work in the RTM build.
>
> Rasool: Is there probably any other way?
>
> Sergey Tkachenko (author): I have not found it.

From this and other articles, I get the feeling that this registry value was originally created for Windows 8 notifications. It was carried over into Windows 10, until build 10240 or so, at which point Microsoft decided to stop allowing users to decide via registry entries.